# Nested QUERY returning data outside expected results

Tags: google-sheets

I am working on a project to extract a subset of a linked sheet using `IMPORTRANGE` and `QUERY` (using `CONTAINS` as a filter). These are musical works by composers from historically underrepresented backgrounds, so I have to filter by a demographic code (hidden) and a genre (shown).

My current method's results are mainly good, but some entries that don't match my criteria (i.e., genre-type) are trickling through (*link below*). Each tab of the spreadsheet should contain one genre from the original list (e.g., Orchestra, Concert Band, Jazz Ensemble), but at least four entries from other genres appear, regardless of the sheet's coded genre.

Is there a way to adjust my `QUERY` to prevent this bleed-through, or should I rewrite the formula using `FILTER` or another similar command?

Link to sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ViXyrF5aaBCLp0izs5kLJpol77o-JZF4WYeD2C8DXTs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your last "or" clause. try adding brackets to group your or statements together:

```
=query(importrange("1NxLcOH13Dxmg0VQMWQtjj_eJ38xyQ-BDV9J-t77hCDM", "New Works!A1:M"), "SELECT Col2, Col4, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12 WHERE Col12 CONTAINS 'Orchestra' AND ((Col3 > 1 and Col3 < 6) or (Col5 > 1 and Col5 < 6)) ORDER by Col12, Col7, Col2 asc", 1)
```